# how to deploy project without dll file in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

when I deploy a project, all of `dll` file will be export although I set build action property is embedded resources
I want to setup deploy configuration in visual studio 2010 without some `*.dll` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reference section, you set copy to local property is false